# Disable then reenable a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following as a timestamp. I would like a button to disable it (so that I can edit without it recording times) and a button to enable it again.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.column = 12 And Target.Row = 9 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    End If
ElseIf Target.column = 12 And (Target.Row >= 10 And Target.Row <= 600) Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Target.Offset(-1, 5).Value = ""
    Else
        Target.Offset(-1, 5).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

use a toggle button, returns true or false, then have the 1st line,`if togglebutton then exit sub`

Answer (score 0):

Use a button which will update cell ZZ200(or as per your choice) with value "ON" or "OFF" and the put your code inside the condition as below :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ZZ200").Value = "ON" Then
        If Target.Column = 12 And Target.Row = 9 Then
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
            Else
                Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            End If
        ElseIf Target.Column = 12 And (Target.Row >= 10 And Target.Row <= 600) Then
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                Target.Offset(-1, 5).Value = ""
            Else
                Target.Offset(-1, 5).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't work for me as it won't run. Any ideas? Also, I'm running this on mac excel, which is slightly different

Comment: Can you share the file, so i could check the issue.